# Firebase push notification - icon and link does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification to a device using Javascript. As described here:

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-js/messaging/readme/

When I run the file, the push notification arrives on the device, but the icon is missing and clicking on the notification does not open the specified URL. What am I doing wrong?

```
var key = 'MYKEY';
var to = 'MYDEVICETOKEN';
var notification = {
  'title': 'Portugal vs. Denmark',
  'body': '5 to 1',
  'icon': 'https://www.example/myicon.jpg',
  'click_action': 'https://www.example/url.html'
};

fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'key=' + key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  'body': JSON.stringify({
    'notification': notification,
    'to': to
  })
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
})
```